# Problem scraping data from web page using jsoup

Tags: android, html-parsing, web-scraping, screen-scraping, jsoup

```
package com.example.abc;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    
            try {
                String uri="http://www.example.com/";
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(uri).get();

                
                
                Elements lk= doc.getElementsByTag("a");
                String lss=null;
                for(Element links : lk)
                {
                    lss=links.text();
                }
                
                TextView t4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                
                t4.setText(lss);
                
            } catch (IOException e) {
                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        
}


}
```

/* also i have given  inside my manifest file ,but my program crashes when i run it and it shows unfortunately,abc has stopped. I am a beginner to scraping in android.So any help is greatly appreciated */

```
/*this is my stack trace.*/

            08-09 18:00:01.033: W/dalvikvm(3106): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.abc/com.example.abc.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:425)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:153)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at com.example.abc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:79)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            08-09 18:00:01.094: E/AndroidRuntime(3106):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: The on screen messaging is not used for debugging.  Check LogCat for the actual stack trace output which will tell you more specifically why your app has crashed.  At a glance, it appears you've made a network request on the main UI thread, which by design will automatically crash the app.

Answer (score 0):

Is either the site link u were using has a problem or u haven't set network permission (uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET")  or the emulator or device ur using has an internet problem.

You should also move the text view above the try method like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
TextView t4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

try{//type code here
}

i ran on on java without using android libraries/concept and it worked fine without errors.